# Chord theory for B5#4

Tags: chord-theory

I have just recently Re-learned the Loverboy song "Working For The Weekend" from a score borrowed from the library. The first three chords in the intro are B5, B5#4, and Bsus4. My question only relates to the B5#4.

How do you read it: B-five-sharp-four or some other way?

What is the theory on building this chord? Is it just a power chord with a sharp fourth tone added?

Comment: It's a passing chord, between B5 and Bsus4, chromatically.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't played for about 5 years due to illness and I'm trying to remember the music theory as I relearn songs I played many years ago.

Comment: Tim's comment is the correct answer.  I think he should post it as an answer!  (Too bad we can't vote for comments!)

Answer (score 1):

As @Tim said in comments the scale steps ^5 ^#4 ^4 are a chromatic embellishment over the root. I think you could say it's all just one embellished chord, no chord change.

From an expressive point of view the ^#4 is a nice spicy dissonance and the ^4 is 'unresolved' meaning the ^4 doesn't go down to the chord tone ^3. The combined dissonance and non-resolution make for a great, attention grabbing introduction.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've copied those chord symbols quite correctly?   B5(add#4) would make sense.   B5#4 is nonsense. B5, by definition is a two-note chord.

Here's what seems to happen, though this version is transposed to C major.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. The score I borrowed from the library did not have parentheses or add, just B5#4.

Comment: Transposed to Cmajor, with a Cminor key sig?

Comment: Fair point!   C minor it is.